# Webpack – How to get why one chunk depends on another chunk

Tags: webpack

For example, after the build, at `stats.json` I see

```
{
  "errors": [],
  "warnings": [],
  "publicPath": "https://localhost:5200/",
  "namedChunkGroups": {
    "A": {
      "chunks": ["B", "C"],
      "assets": ["B.js", "C.js"],
      "children": {},
      "childAssets": {}
    }
  }
}
```

This means, that chunk `A` depends on chunk `B` and chunk `C`.
I need to understand how does it depend? Which modules from `B` and `C` are imported at `A`.

I suppose there should be some Webpack Plugin, but I can't find it.

Comment: Could you create a GH repo with that example?

Comment: You can try dropping the stats.json file into the analyzer here https://webpack.github.io/analyse/ to have a more readable output. Apart from that, the chunking highly depends on your webpack configuration, so you might want to share that as well (esp. the part where you configure how it should split chunks).